# HttpClient, seems so hard to use it correctly

Tags: .net-core, httpclient

just another question about the correct usage of `HttpClient`, because unless i am missing something, I find contradicting information about `HttpClient` in Microsoft Docs. These two links are the source of my confusion:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/antipatterns/improper-instantiation/#how-to-fix-the-problem
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#typed-clients

First one states that the best approach is a shared singleton `HttpClient` instance, the second that the  `AddHttpClient<TypedClient>()` registers the service as transient, and more specifically (copied from that URL):

> The typed client is registered as transient with DI. In the preceding
>   code, `AddHttpClient` registers `GitHubService` as a transient service.
>   This registration uses a factory method to:
>
> 1. Create an instance of `HttpClient`.
> 2. Create an instance of `GitHubService`, passing in the instance of `HttpClient` to its constructor.

I was always using `AddHttpClient<TypedClient>()` and feeling safe, but now i am puzzled again... And making things worse, I found this [github issue comment](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/1345) by @rynowak which states:

> If you are building a library that you plan to distribute, I would
>   strongly suggest that you don't take a dependency on
>   `IHttpClientFactory` at all, and have your consumers pass in an
>   `HttpClient` instance.

Why this is important to me? Because, I am in a process of creating a library that mainly does two things:

1. Retrieve an access token from a token service (`IdentityServer4`)
2. Use that token to access a protected resource

And I am following the typed clients approach described in the [link 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#typed-clients) above:

```cs
//from https://github.com/georgekosmidis/IdentityServer4.Contrib.HttpClientService/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4.Contrib.HttpClientService/Extensions/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs
services.AddHttpClient<IIdentityServerHttpClient, IdentityServerHttpClient>()
        .SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

Any advises or examples of how a concrete implementation based on `HttpClient` looks like, will be very welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: The typed client is injected as transient, but the `HttpClient` inside it may not be.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Davig, but the docs state: "This registration used a factory method to: 1. Create an instance of HttpClient. 2...". You mean this is not well documented, and actually only one instance is created and then reused?

Comment: Check this thread for a detailed answer: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/17204